# How to identify primary keys in an existing database table

Tags: databaselink

I would like to identify the primary keys in a DB table using DatabaseLink commands trying to exclude SQLExecute.  It seems like SQLTableInformation or SQLColumnInformation may not show that information.

Comment: SQLTablePrimaryKeys?  https://reference.wolfram.com/language/DatabaseLink/ref/SQLTablePrimaryKeys.html

Comment: Yes, that's what I needed.  For some reason it escaped my radar. Thanks!